# Getting empty spanId and traceId in splunk logs

Tags: trace

Getting empty spanId and traceId as below in splunk logs:
2023-05-17 05:24:20.729 INFO spanId{} traceId{}
What could be the issue ?

I verified spring cloud sleuth dependency in pom.xml, but still it doesn't print the id
I am expecting some Id should be present inside the braces , any configuration I am missing out ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.